# unable to use display suite template files

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, display-suite

i use display suite to style my taxonomy page and it suggests me some template files but i am not able to use that file, i put them in place but they do not include,

do you know how it will works please ? or any references ?!

this is my display suite screen

[image]

and i place file ds-reset--node-article-article-ds.tpl.php into address sites/all/modules/contrib/ds/layouts/ds_reset
but not thing gana happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(would be a comment if I could :) You're supposed to put your template file in /sites/all/themes/your_theme/templates/, not in the DS folder.